# How to prevent Sitecore resolving the Language based on the URL

Tags: multilingual, urls

Our site is resolving some relative urls as languages, where it should be resolving items instead.

e.g. 
`mydomain.com/eu` should be resolving the item `EU` under the `home` item. 
Instead, Sitecore is resolving the `home` item with the language as *Basque (EU)*

What is an effective way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you also running your site multilingual that you want to work for some languages? Or do you want all language-interpretation removed from URLs?

Comment: There is only one language on the site

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want FilePath based language resolving, simple do below setting in **Sitecore.config**:

```
<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />
```

This will do nothing but ignoring the **StripLanguage** processor from **preprocessRequest** pipeline.

---

By default first item (after domain name), Sitecore checks whether it's a language or not. If it's a registered language of .NET, Sitecore will consider it a language, else will consider it as an Item inside Home. So, above configuration should fix your issue.

Comment: Make sure you patch this, don't edit the `sitecore.config` directly

Comment: Do you mean Web.config?

Comment: Yeah, in Web.config for older versions. After sc 8, it's Sitecore.config

Comment: To Richard's point:Patching is a best practice so you don't break the upgrade path. Everytime you need to change a sitecore out of the box configuration make sure you patch that. You can find more information on patching here: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Patch%20Files/