# Sitecore 8.2 update 6 display a not found item

Tags: sitecore-client

Today, I found a weird issue in Sitecore 8.2 update 6, I have setup the Sitecore in local using Sitecore Installer and give the sc82u6 as host name;

Then, the Sitecore default page up and run, and I can see the banner as well as Sitecore Experience Platform rich text

But when I browse the site as following url http://sc82u6/ps the page is still display, what's the problem?

[image: 8]

I guess that will display Sitecore page not found, but no, can someone can please explain about it? Is it Sitecore's issue?

[image]
I have been working on a cooperation site which is using that Sitecore version and client would like to create the item name /ps

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: So what is happening here is the /ps is being caught by the language resolver, does stripping out language impact you? Or is it an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Marek.

> If you don't want FilePath based language resolving, simple do below
>   setting in Sitecore.config:
>
> `<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />`

Refer to https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/132/3451